# How can I set the public access type while creating a container through code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-for-java

I am trying to create a container through code and I need to set the public access type to public. I am trying to do it like this with the method createWithResponse(Map <String, String> metadata, PublicAccessType accessType, Duration timeout, Context context) but I am not understanding what should I put for the metadata variable and the context. What does it mean? I would appreciate an example. If I pass null in the duration variable, it means that it does not expire?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for this method [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobcontainerasyncclient.createwithresponse?view=azure-java-stable):

- You can pass `null` for `metadata` if you do not want to set any metadata for the container.
- For `context`, you can try passing `null` again or try `Context.NONE`. For more details on the context, please see this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.core.util.context?view=azure-java-stable).
- `timeout` property is the operation timeout property. If your operation takes more time than the value specified for this property, you will get an exception.